# Listview metadata import

Tags: metadata

Is there a way to import the salesforce metadata back into salesforce?

I would to export export lead list view metadata change the sobject from lead to account and load it back. I can retrieve it with workbench but i dnt know how to load it back.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a package.xml file to deploy it via workbench or VS Code. A sample xml file for retrieving the account list view is:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Account.AccountTeam</members>
        <name>ListView</name>
    </types>
    <version>48.0</version>
</Package>
```

To deploy back again after some change in it via Workbench:-

To perform a Deploy operation (Upload changes from the configuration data to Salesforce):

1. Create a folder the package XML file in the root and a sub level folder with the component name.
2. Zip the folder.
3. Visit the [Workbench site](https://workbench.developerforce.com/) and login with username and password, if not already logged in.
4. Click the Migration tab.
5. Select the Deploy section.
6. Click the Choose file option.
7. Check the following if applicable to the your scenario:

> ```
> Auto Update Package
> Check Only
> Ignore Warnings
> Perform Retrieve
> Purge On Delete
> Rollback On Error
> Single Package
> ```

8. Confirm all of the options for deployment.
9. Click on the Deploy button when ready.
10. Wait for process to become completed.
11. Confirm the results deploy successfully, if not check the file for any errors.

Read more here:- [Use Metadata API to retrieve and deploy using Workbench](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000315117&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)

Read more about ListView metadata here:- [ListView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_listview.htm)